# IF.. ELSE IF statements in SQL wont print

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

Anyone know why this wont print anything?

It's in a stored procedure

No error message just returns blank.

There are IIF statements in this stored proc that return variable ints.

The variables are all SELECT COUNT() queries.

It works if I substitute the PRINT statements for:

SELECT @countA; or SELECT @countB; ect

```
IF(@countA > @countB) AND (@countC >= 3 OR @countD >= 3))
           BEGIN 
                  PRINT 'YO';
                 
           END 
       ELSE IF(@countA > @countB AND (@countC >= 3 OR @countD >= 3))
           BEGIN 
                
                PRINT 'YO';
           END
       ELSE IF(@countE > @countF AND (@countG >= 3 OR @countH >= 3))
           BEGIN 
                  
                  PRINT 'YO';
           END 
       ELSE
           BEGIN
                PRINT 'YO';
            END ;
```

Fixed by changing to a variable and selecting it instead of printing:

```
DECLARE @YO varchar(2)
SET @YO = 'YO'

IF(@countA > @countB) AND (@countC >= 3 OR @countD >= 3))
           BEGIN 
                  SELECT @YO;
                 
           END 
       ELSE IF(@countA > @countB AND (@countC >= 3 OR @countD >= 3))
           BEGIN 
                
                SELECT @YO;
           END
       ELSE IF(@countE > @countF AND (@countG >= 3 OR @countH >= 3))
           BEGIN 
                  
                  SELECT @YO;
           END 
       ELSE
           BEGIN
                SELECT @YO;
            END ;
```

Comment: Is this in a stored procedure?

Comment: Always include the *exact* error message you're getting.

Comment: @tadman not a stored procedure yet but all variables are declared and set above it

Comment: `IF` only works inside of stored procedures. This will not work as a query.

Comment: @tadman there is no error message it just doesnt return a value and only returns a value if I use SELECT @countA; instead of the PRINT

Comment: @tadman thanks, I wonder why it works with the SELECT query outside the stored procedure

Comment: MySQL does not support `if` unless it is in a programming block.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Typo,  meant SQL not MySQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use sql server 2014 and it fully supports ifs and declares

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the queries?

Comment: @MartinSmith Just on Microsoft server management studio 2014

Comment: and you are looking in the "messages" tab for the `print` output?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks bro, feel silly now haha. It's better that I put it as a variable for my purpose though at least